# Kivy: WARNING stderr: AttributeError: 'CardFinder' object has no attribute 'textbox_franchise'

Tags: python, selenium, kivy

I'm building an app with Kivy and Selenium. The app consists in a card's prize calculator. It picks the card name and it searchs on cardmarket.com it's name and it's prize in base of it's condition (used, new, ecc..). The app isn't complete, but i was trying to build a basic graphic window with kivy.. Here is the entire code, I haven't used .kv files.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

list_franchise = ["Yu-Gi-Oh", "Pokémon", "Magic", "Dragon Ball Super", "Flesh And Blood", 
                "Digimon", "Force of Will", "Final Fantasy", "World of Warcraft",
                "Star Wars Destiny", "Weiss Schwarz", "Dragoborne", "My Little Pony",
                "The Spoils"]

class CardFinder(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        Window.size = (360,640)
        self.window.size_hint = (0.8, 0.9)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

        self.window.add_widget(Image(source="assets/logo.png"))

        label_franchise = Label(text="Insert the franchise:", font_size="25sp", font_name="fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf",
                            pos_hint={"center_y": 0.2})

        textbox_franchise = TextInput(font_size="18sp", font_name="fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf", size_hint=(1, 0.2), halign="center",
                                    padding_y="12sp")

        button_franchise = Button(text="Continue", font_size="23sp", font_name="fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf", 
                                size_hint=(1, 0.2), halign="center")
        button_franchise.bind(on_press=self.find_prize)

        self.window.add_widget(label_franchise)
        self.window.add_widget(textbox_franchise)
        self.window.add_widget(button_franchise)

        return self.window

    def find_prize(self, instance):
        if self.textbox_franchise.text.lower() == "Pokemon":
            self.textbox_franchise.text = "Pokémon"
        if self.textbox_franchise.text.lower() == "YuGiOh":
            self.textbox_franchise.text = "Yu-Gi-Oh"
        if textbox_franchise.text.lower() in lista_franchise:
            self.window.remove_widget(label_franchise)
            self.window.remove_widget(textbox_franchise)
            self.window.remove_widget(button_franchise)
        else:
            dlg = MessageBox(self, titleheader="Not valid", message="Franchise not supported in this app.", 
                            options={"OK": "pass"})

def search_prize2(): # this function contains my beta app and it isn't executed. The                            
                     # commands in this function will be transfered in the 
                     # "find_prize" function, so this function is actually useless.
    cardmarket_url = "https://www.cardmarket.com/it/"

    print("\nChe cosa ti interessa?\n\n")
    index_prodotto = 0
    

    while (index_prodotto <= 13):
        print(f"  [{str(index_prodotto+1)}] - {prodotti[index_prodotto]}")
        index_prodotto = index_prodotto + 1

    scelto = False

    while (scelto == False):
        try:
            prodotto = prodotti[int(input("\nInserisci il numero: "))-1]
            scelto = True
        except:
            print("Devi inserire un numero da 1 a 14.")

    print(f"\nHai scelto {prodotto}.")

    if prodotto == "Yu-Gi-Oh":
        prodotto = "YuGiOh"
    if prodotto == "Pokémon":
        prodotto = "Pokemon"
    if prodotto == "Force of Will":
        prodotto = "FoW"
    if prodotto == "World of Warcraft":
        prodotto = "WoW"
    if prodotto == "Spoils":
        prodotto = "Spoils"

    chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver))
    driver.get(cardmarket_url+prodotto.replace(" ", ""))

    cercato = False

    while (cercato == False):
        prodotto = input("\nInserisci il nome della carta che vuoi cercare: ")
        rarita = input("Inserisci la rarità della carta (altrimenti premi 'invio'): ")
        numero = input("Ora inserisci il numero della carta: ")
        if prodotto != "":
            cercato = True
        else:
            print("Inserisci il nome del prodotto.")

    prodotto = prodotto+" "+rarita

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ProductSearchInput").send_keys(prodotto)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-btn").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="col-12 col-md-8 px-2 flex-column"]/a[contains(text(),"'+prodotto+'/span[containt(text(),"'+numero+'")")]').click()

    input()

CardFinder().run()
```

The error is at the beginning of the search_prize function, and it is

```
if self.textbox_franchise.text.lower() == "Pokemon":
2022-07-10 15:43:53,288 WARNING stderr:     if self.textbox_franchise.text.lower() == "Pokemon":
 AttributeError: 'CardFinder' object has no attribute 'textbox_franchise'
2022-07-10 15:43:53,289 WARNING stderr: AttributeError: 'CardFinder' object has no attribute 'textbox_franchise'
```

anyone can help me?

PS: sorry for grammatical errors, but I'm not english‍♂️

Comment: Try replacing `textbox_franchise` with `self.textbox_franchise` in method `build`. Also apply this change to others if necessary.

Comment: I've already tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: Try stripping down your code either by removing or modifying all dependencies. But keep it minimal and reproducible.